# Why does g++ link the standard library?

Tags: c++

I have a simple piece of c++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  cout << "Hello World!";
  return 0;
}
```

When I generate the assembly of this code I get a huge assembly file which I presume is compilation of the standard library. Why does this happen and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Define "Huge". I get a 7.4kb file using -O3.

Comment: @mabs: If you're sure you don't want any of the standard headers you can pass `-nostdinc` to the compiler's command line.

Comment: +1 to mfontanini, and please specify your compiler and settings.

Comment: The `<iostream>` header is likely to include other headers containing templates implementing the streams. The expanded templates will end up in your file.

Comment: You say you "presume" that the bulk you see is from the standard library. That means you're not even sure if what you're asking is a valid question. How can anyone answer when you're not even sure what you're asking? The first question you need to ask is what the bulk in the file *is*. *Then* ask why it's there. And to know what the bulk is, you need to tell us how you generated it (compiler and linker versions and command lines).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much of the standard library is made up of templates. When you use a template it gets specialized for your use and the specialization will be part of your binary. This can't be avoided, although you can ensure a specialization is only in a single one of your translation units using extern templates.

Answer (score -2):

std::cout is part of the standard library.

You used it.

Pretty obvious really.

Iostreams are templates, so the code is emitted in your object, not in a shared library, but with optimizations enabled the (stripped) size shouldn't be larger than necessary to implement your helloworld.

See http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq.html#Hello-world for another answer.

Comment: if you put it this way then why doesn't `printf` et al get included when you use it? and this is a rhetorical question, of course.